# Why did my workflow rule run? (A spin on the usual question)

Tags: workflow, error

I have a workflow rule that fired unexpectedly.

The workflow rule was set to evaluate **when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria**

The workflow rule criteria are:

- Case_Worker__c != null
- Type != Billing
- Case Owner = Customer Care (a queue)

This workflow rule fired (causing an email alert to be sent out to some of my company's customers) when I had my intern update the ContactId on the `Case`, **with no other fields being changed**

I was able to reproduce this behavior myself (after making sure that no more of these emails were erroneously sent off to our customers). I was also able to reproduce this issue when updating the `AccountId` field on the same `Case` record.

After I narrowed the cause down to this workflow rule, I took a look at my org's `Case Assignment Rules` and `Case Auto-Response Rules` and found nothing that would be setting or overwriting any of the 3 fields included in the workflow rule's criteria.

Why do updates to `ContactId` or `AccountId` cause this workflow rule to fire?

**Edit:**

I also checked the 2 triggers I have on `Case` (these triggers were inherited, moving everything to my trigger framework is work for my downtime). The only `Case` field updated in my triggers is `Parent_Account__c`.

After that, I checked every other trigger in my org, as well as every apex class in my org. I was unable to find any instance of any of the 3 fields used in the workflow criteria being altered.

**Edit 2:**

Here's a minimum viable reproduction.

The prerequisites are:

1. Have at least 2 different `Contacts` in the org you are testing this in
2. Have no mandatory lookup filters on the `Contact Name` (`ContactId` is the API name) field. Alternatively, ensure your 2 contacts will meet a mandatory lookup filter
3. Have no existing workflow rules on `Case` that contain workflow field updates which update the `Contact Name` (`ContactId`) or `Web Email` (`SuppliedEmail`) fields
4. Comment out any portions of triggers or apex that update the `Contact Name`/`ContactId` or `Web Email` (`SuppliedEmail`) fields
5. Double check that Case Assignment and Case Auto Response rules won't interfere with the `Contact Name`/`ContactId` or `Web Email` (`SuppliedEmail`) fields

After that is done

1. Create a new workflow rule on `Case`
2. Set evaluation criteria to `Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`

   - Set the rule criteria to `Case:Web email equals admin@localhost.com`
3. Create a new workflow field update (immediate action)

   - Set it to update the `Description` field of `Case`
   - Use a formula `Description + 'Last workflow field update at: ' + TEXT(NOW())`
4. Don't forget to activate the workflow rule
5. Either create a new `Case`, or use an existing one
6. Populate the `Contact Name` (`ContactId` is the API name) field
7. Update the `Web Email` (`SuppliedEmail` is the API name) to `admin@localhost.com`
8. Observe that the Description field has been updated
9. Update the `Contact Name` field
10. Observe that the Description field has been updated again, even though the `Web Email` field has not changed

Comment: Seems reasonable a trigger might update Case Worker in that scenario?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I went through all of my triggers to check for updates to any of these 3 fields, I'll edit that in.

Comment: I can give it a quick shot. I finished my work week a few hours ago. So, if my quick MVR doesn't work out, I won't get back to this until sometime on Monday (I'm in UTC - 6 land)

Comment: @AdrianLarson MVR is up. There are some hoops to jump through, but those hoops are necessary to avoid other potential influences.

Comment: @cropredy That's valuable real-world experience right there! In all seriousness though, this intern's big project is working on de-duping our Contacts. Updating the `ContactId` on `Case` is one of the last steps in the procedure I wrote for my intern to follow. We were doing a test run in our QA environment. I immediately took responsibility for the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By some amount of luck, I was able to do a Google search that led me to the [Workflow considerations page](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&language=en) on help.salesforce.com.

On that page is this gem

> Workflow rules are triggered when a standard object in a master-detail relationship is re-parented, **even if the object's evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria**.

The only issue is that the `ContactId` field on `Case` is a lookup relationship (verified by looking at the standard Case fields in Salesforce proper, and through the apex workbench) instead of a master-detail relationship.

Despite that, standard lookups in Salesforce can show some unusual, albeit documented, behavior. The relationship type between `OpportunityLineItem` and `Opportunity` is technically a lookup relationship, and yet we can create rollup summary fields on `Opportunity` summarizing `OpportunityLineItem` records. We can also roll up fields from `Opportunity` records on `Accounts` (`AccountId` on `Opportunity` again being a lookup relationship)

So the only answer that I can arrive at is that, while the `ContactId` field on `Case` is a lookup field, it's treated by Salesforce as  **meh, close enough I guess...**  when it comes to ignoring the `subsequently` part of the `any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria` workflow evaluation setting.

As mentioned in the question, this appears to be the case for the `AccountId` field on `Case` as well. I haven't tested this with any other standard relationship fields on other standard sObjects.

Comment: Are you able to do rollup summary fields through this relationship? That would certainly lend credence to your theory.

Comment: I thought I tried this, but I wasn't sure...so I just attempted to create a rollup summary field on `Contact` summarizing a field on `Case`, and I cannot create the field.